# What kind of material can act as storage, float and withstand firepower?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

I actually rediscovered an old story I wrote five years ago and there was this supposedly synthetic material that can float, be programmed to be directed where to be delivered and can carry luggage (I'm assuming ~100kg) and can withstand firepower from the tumultuous society that's currently in civil unrest against a tyrant.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if something similar in reality could be incorporated even theoretically.

Comment: Can you give us more information? I understand generally what you are asking for, but I need some details. For example, what kind of firepower do the tyrant's troops have at their disposal?

Comment: So... Armoured Amazon delivery drones? In practice, almost any material can float if shaped correctly - modern ships are made of materials that would sink if not shaped like boats and any object can be programmed by the simple addition of a computer. Unless you're talking about the kind of liquid metal terminators that are popular in the movies that are intelligent and can change shape it would be great to get more clarity about what you're asking for here.

Comment: classic gunfire, deadly light gun rays

it's seethrough as well.and no doesn't change shape, they're honestly kind of like spherical bubbles. except not as weak as a bubble

Comment: Wood fits all those criteria, especially harder woods when you turn it into a ship.

Comment: Concrete works as well.  Concrete floats when formed properly to have large air cavities within it.

Comment: Floats in what? Freshwater? Saltwater? Air? The vacuum of space? Liquid Mercury? Lava lakes?

Comment: float in air but for it be able to float in literally anything sounds great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aluminium OxyNitride**

So, if you're a Star Trek fan, then you'll have heard of transparent aluminum and as it turns out, it's now a thing. [Aluminium Oxynitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride) is also called transparent aluminum and is marketed under the name ALON as well. It's quite bulletproof, is lighter than most bulletproof products, and if it could be shaped into an empty sphere like you describe in your comments, would pretty much fit the brief of all but the programmability (and perhaps the maneuvering to the assigned location). Fortunately, because it doesn't have to change shape we can add to the inside of the sphere a very simple solution to this - a computer. Hell, even just a NavMan if all you need it to do is get somewhere.

Getting it to be able to move around as well is a bit tricker, but you could put external 'fans' or turbines on it to get it to move in a desired direction, especially when alfoat, meaning that you pretty much have all you need, and a little more. Because it's (mostly) transparent, you can even tell at a glance whether the bubble is taken or not. Of course that works both ways as it means that pirates can pick and choose what bubbles to go after, but getting into them is going to be harder because... Well, transparent aluminium.

Comment: Closest thing to what I'm looking for!! Thank you! I'll refer to this material more (and wow I should really get around to watching Star Trek one day haha)

Answer (score 4):

**You're talking about the U.S.S. *Constitution***

The *Constitution* floats, can carry 100kg of cargo (or more!) with ease, and (with favorable winds) can sail where directed.  Her hull is 22" thick and consists of three layers of oak (white oak, live oak, white oak), and she is nicknamed "Old Ironsides" because cannonballs were observed literally bouncing off her sides during a battle with HMS *Guerriere*.

[image]

If this is not the accepted answer, the question may need more clarification.

Comment: Har har matey! I added more deets in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

**Nanites**

Theoretically nanites can form any shape object could easily form a foam or a boat as to float as well as move under it's own power.

It could also form shapes to absorb gunfire and make shields or armour like I[ron Man's](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Armor:_Mark_L) and [Black Panther'](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Panther_Habit)s armour in Marvel comics